# How much more space efficient is a SQL Server database compared to saving C# data to XML files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, database

I have a big number of big datasets that I want to save them to my hard drive.

I've found that if I use the `WriteXML` method, I am getting XMLs of a size of more than 8MB, and I will have hundreds of those in the future.

How much more efficient would a SQL Server database be for storing my datasets? Or is there a more efficient way to save them, compared to what I am doing?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: XML is about portability not efficiency

Comment: XML is a verbose text format - it's about the least space efficient way to store data. In general, JSON would be more space efficient, and a binary format would be more efficient still. A database would typically be close to a binary format - note that this all assumes it's sensibly implemented...!

Comment: You could also zip your xmls, that's how the "new" office formats (docx) etc work